# Managing photos on a small iPhone iOS 12

Tags: ios, icloud, photos

Can anyone confirm that this is correct?

"If you turn off iCloud photos on any of your apple devices (mac, iPhone, iPad) you are then presented with the choice as to whether already downloaded photos will stay on that device or be deleted on that device.”

I am afraid to try it for fear of permanently losing photos, but I have a small, 15 GB iPhone and have used almost all its capacity.